# qTip tooltip wont work

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, asp.net-mvc-3, tooltip

I am trying to get qTip to work, but it doesnt display any tooltips. this is my code:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js")" type="text/javascript">

</script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.qtip-1.0.0-rc3.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Create the tooltips only on document load
    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#question").each(function() { 
        qtip({
        content: 'Dark themes are all the rage!',
        show: 'mouseover',
        hide: 'mouseout'
        style: { 
        name: 'dark', // Inherit from preset style

   }
});

</script>
```

And i have a div container that looks like this:

```
<div id="question">@Html.LabelFor(y => item.question_wording, item.question_wording)</div>
```

what have i done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should look something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#question").each(function() { 
        $(this).qtip({
            content: 'Dark themes are all the rage!',
            style: { 
                name: 'dark' // Inherit from preset style
            }
            show: 'mouseover',
            hide: 'mouseout'
       });
   });
});
```

Not quite sure if the hide/show options are correct.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried to replace the code with yours, but it still doesnt show anything in firefox or chrome

Comment: In chrome, open the developer tools. Do you see any errors when your page loads on the console tab?

Comment: $('#question') returns 1 element only, you should use a class instead of an id

Comment: I have changed the code to this: <script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#question").each(function() { 
        $(this).qtip({
            content: 'Dark themes are all the rage!',
            style: { 
                name: 'cream' // Inherit from preset style
            },
            position: {
                corner: {
                    target: 'topMiddle',
                    tooltip: 'bottomLeft'
                    }
                 }
       });
   });
});


</script>

Comment: It only displays a tool tip for the first div. If i change the id to class in the div it doesnt display anything. Developer tools says no errors

Comment: change `$('#question')` to `$('.question')`